# Global sections for a locally free sheaf over curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $B$ be a complete algbraic curve of genus $g$, and $\mathcal{E}$ be a semi-stable locally free sheaf of rank $r$ over $B$. Assume that the slope of $\mathcal{E}$ is $\mu(\mathcal E):=\frac{\deg \mathcal E}{r}\leq g-1$. Is it possible to choose an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ with $\deg\mathcal L=0$ and $\dim H^0(B,\,\mathcal E\otimes \mathcal L)=0$?

PS: If $r=1$, then it is known that we can always choose such an invertible sheaf $\mathcal L$ since a general invertible sheaf of degree $\leq g-1$ has no global section.

Comment: See the paper of Raynaud "Sections des fibres vectoriels sur une courbe". (For $r=2$ the answer is yes but in general the answer is no.)

Comment: Online access to Raynaud article: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=BSMF_1982__110__103_0

Comment: The link above is broken, a new one: http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/bsmf.1955.pdf